# Do I require HttpsRedirection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

```json
"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:443",
        "Protocols": "Http1"
      },
      "gRPC": {
        "Url": "https://*:8443",
        "Protocols": "Http2"
      }
    }
```

I am using the above kestrel configuration to run my ASP.NET Core Web API app. I have the required Self signed development certificate for development purposes and the CA certificate configuration for Server deployments.

My application is not public facing and I can configure the clients to the APIs over SSL.
So, As seen above, I am not exposing an HTTP endpoint.

Do I require `UseHttpsRedirection` or `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT` configuration as I am not exposing a non-secure Http port?

Comment: TBH if its an internal webapi that is not public facing, you might as well use plain http.

Comment: This is a production application  and not yep public facing. I am not expecting to allow connection over HTTP. in such a case, what is ideal?

Comment: All my ASP.NET kestrel servers are not public fasing either - they sit behind a public nginx that passes requests on (via unix sockets in my case). If that is your setup too, then you don't need to encrypt data within a private network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for `UseHttpsRedirection` in this scenario, where Kestrel listens only on *https*. The first step in the `HttpsRedirectionMiddleware` is to check whether the established connection is already on *https*: [if it is, the middleware does nothing (it's a no-op)](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Middleware/HttpsPolicy/src/HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.cs#L80):

> ```
> if (context.Request.IsHttps)
> {
>     return _next(context);
> }
> ```